# Gzip specific controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, gzip

Is there a way to add Gzip for one method or controller in spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/system", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
@Gzip //<- Something similar this,
public ApiResponse status() throws Exception{

}
```

I dont want to enable it for the entire server using tomcat configuration, since my clients are not yet ready for consuming gzip,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638345/how-to-decode-gzip-compressed-request-body-in-spring-mvc

Comment: But these all examples are explaining to gzip at filter level, I am looking to have the decision at my controller or controller method level

Answer (score 1):

You can put `java.io.OutputStream` or `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` (for specific gzip HTTP headers) to your Controller method as parameter wrapping it with `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` before writing the content to the client

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/system", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public void status(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
   try(GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
       // write to out the content
   }
}
```