# Handling gzipped requests in a Spring Boot REST application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot REST app (1.5.6.RELEASE).  I would like gzip compression incoming and outgoing.  As per this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html I have set

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=...
```

But this seems to only apply to gzipping responses from my service (and this is what the doc says actually "# If response compression is enabled.").

My problem is that incoming gzipped requests are not being decompressed, resulting in JSON parsing errors.

Does anyone know how I can turn on request decompression in my Spring Boot app?

**EDIT** An example:

POM snippet:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Controller code:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public String post(@RequestBody Map<String, String> request) {
        return request.get("key");
   }
}
```

Test using curl:

```
$ echo '{ "key":"hello" }' > body
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @body http://localhost:8080 # prints 'hello'
$ echo '{ "key":"hello" }' | gzip > body.gz
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary @body.gz http://localhost:8080 # fails
```

The gzipped call fails with message:

```
{"timestamp":1505843443456,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\\r, \\n, \\t) is allowed between tokens; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\\r, \\n, \\t) is allowed between tokens\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@50ebec25; line: 1, column: 2]","path":"/"}
```

Comment: how do you issue compressed requests?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20507007/46673,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/16638345/466738, https://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests

Comment: @diginoise I don't control the client

Comment: Show us some code! What does your controller look like? What is the client sending (HTTP headers and body), what error are you getting, etc

Comment: @Brian Clozel, done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `server.compression.*` configuration keys are about HTTP response compression only. I'm not aware of any general solution, nor if servers support that natively.

You can support that by using a Servlet filter that does just that, but Spring Boot does not offer that feature.

Comment: or you put your servlet container behind Apache and let Apache handle it: https://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests#answer-56707

Comment: well, I saw some questions about whether nginx does do that or not - https://serverfault.com/questions/334215/how-do-i-configure-nginx-to-accept-gzip-requests - from 2011. But I couldn't find anything more recent which states that nginx now allows request compression (searching on `content-encoding` through the nginx docs)

Comment: Yeah, your best bet these days would be to use HTTP/2 for that.

Comment: Bit of downer really since I'm already using NginX for response compression and SSL. But I haven't finished looking.