# Spring REST controller does not handle gzip compressed input

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have set up my spring boot application to handle HTTP server compression by setting the following properties in `application.properties` according to the documentation:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css
```

Nevertheless, upon receiving gzip compressed input the Spring REST controller does not seem to be able to decode the input. I am getting a `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. Here are the relevant lines from the log:

```
2020-08-17 14:44:41,201 DEBUG [http-nio-9972-exec-4] org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: BEFORE REQUEST: POST /api/v1/observerConfiguration/observer, client=127.0.0.1, headers=[accept-encoding:"gzip", "deflate", content-encoding:"gzip", "deflate", accept:"*/*", user-agent:"Java/11.0.8", host:"localhost:9972", connection:"keep-alive", transfer-encoding:"chunked", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]]
2020-08-17 14:44:41,512 WARN  [http-nio-9972-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver: Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]]
2020-08-17 14:44:41,513 DEBUG [http-nio-9972-exec-4] org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: AFTER REQUEST: POST /api/v1/observerConfiguration/observer, client=127.0.0.1, headers=[accept-encoding:"gzip", "deflate", content-encoding:"gzip", "deflate", accept:"*/*", user-agent:"Java/11.0.8", host:"localhost:9972", connection:"keep-alive", transfer-encoding:"chunked", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]]
```

Is there some additional configuration required to make Spring Boot handle the compressed JSON payload?

The Spring Boot version is `v2.3.2.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does not offer this feature, as it's part of the web server.
One way you can handle this issue is to supply a filter/component that handles incomming requests.

Please see this answer for more information and tips in implementing it as [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63386/erik-nedwidek) suggested: [How to decode Gzip compressed request body in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638345/how-to-decode-gzip-compressed-request-body-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: One thing about Spring is for sure. It *never* does the right thing out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `server.compression.enabled=true` is about the `response`, not the `request`.
For the `request`, you would probably need to write your own `Filter` or use any existing ones.
Looking on internet, I could find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46307903) with some examples that may help.