# org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31))

Tags: spring-webclient, jsonexception

I am getting the following error getting a response of a post method via WebClient(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client)

```
org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:215)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Ȁ
```

I have tried changing the headers of the request as under with **failure** :-

```
headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

or

```
headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

Is it that webclient is unable to process the gzipped response for any reason!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621547/jackson-error-illegal-character-only-regular-white-space-allowed-when-parsi

Comment: yes. Basically i am getting the issue from webclient. The issue is basically how to resolve the same JSonParseException in webclient.

Comment: Can you parse the payload manually? set a debugger or inspect  what the client is sending and try to parse it. also try sending the same post request using a different client "postman, curl..etc"

Comment: Yes when the endpoint is POSTed in postman, it gives JSON response.

Comment: Can test if the token is valid using something like this: https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/46358bc8167fce059d83a1ebdb92b0e7

Comment: I dont think it should be much related to Authentication tokens. Its failing after we receive the response, while parsing jSON.

Answer (score 4):

Remove header ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
You will not get JSON decoding error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31))

If the response length is increased beyond default threshold then response would be gziped and it will give JSON decoding error.

Answer (score 0):

I missed implementing Serializable to the response object.

Comment: I see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I have started getting this exception with Spring boot's feign dependency `spring-cloud-openfeign-core` when I upgrade the version of `spring-cloud-openfeign-core` to `2.2.5.RELEASE`.

For those who upgrade to version 2.2.5.RELEASE or later version will face this issue if they already have the property  `feign.request.compression=true`.

> The technical reason behind this is, in
> `FeignContentGzipEncodingAutoConfiguration` class  the conditional
> property annotation signature changed from
> `@ConditionalOnProperty("feign.compression.request.enabled", matchIfMissing = false)` to `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "feign.compression.request.enabled")`, so by default
> `FeignContentGzipEncodingInterceptor` is triggered. [GitHub reference](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/compare/v2.2.3.RELEASE...v2.2.5.RELEASE#)

**Workaround**

If your calling a spring-boot service which doesn't have a mechanism to handle the `compressed request` then disable the feign request compression using the below property

```
feign.request.compression=false.
```

**NOTE**: Unfortunately, we still don't have the out-of-box solution in spring-boot to handle the compressed request [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299674/handling-gzipped-requests-in-a-spring-boot-rest-application)