# After decompres a request in Spring Boot, how can I trigger an endpoint which is waiting JSON data

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, compression, gzip

I need to compress the calls for a WebApp built on Angular/Spring Boot.

Angular is compressing the request to the Backend with pako and sending in a Blob (thanks to a previous question in stackoverflow)

```
var compressedBody = pako.gzip(JSON.stringify(request.body))
var blobCompressedBody = new Blob([compressedBody]);
const newRequest = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.append('Content-Encoding', 'gzip'), body: blobCompressedBody });
```

Spring Boot is readin the compress request with a filter defined on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26226246/1778299

```
        public GzippedInputStreamWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
       super(request);
        try {
                final InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(request.getInputStream());
                inputStream = in;
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            inputStream = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And now the problem is that the Controller is waiting an application/json data

```
@PostMapping(
        value = "/users",
        consumes = {"application/json"},
        produces = {"application/json"})
ResponseEntity<User> createUser(
        @Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO);
```

And the  endpoint on the Controller can be trigger, because the data is unknown format.

Spring Boot doesn't know how to map the data that we are getting for the UnGZip process, and it's returning :

message:  "Content type '' not supported"

I don't know how to format the data from the request.getInputStream to transform in JSONdata before calling the doFilter(request, response) that the endpoint can be triggered.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you are trying to send Blob data from Angular to Spring Boot. I think it will be easier if you follow this approach:

In the Frontend:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  uploadFile(blobData: Blob): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobData);

    return this.http.post<any>('your_backend_url', formData);
  }
```

In the Backend

```
@PostMapping("/users")
  public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // add Your logic
   // you will get all the data in the file
    return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully");
  }
```

I hope that helpful.